# Adding <solver_io='python'> in the creation of the solver Gurobi with Pyomo can return an error that is not given when <solver_io='python'> is omitted

Tags: python, pyomo, gurobi

I am solving an optimization problem using the library Pyomo of Python and the solver Gurobi. Could you help me please to understand the difference between the following two coding lines?

1) opt = pyo.SolverFactory('gurobi', solver_io='python')

2) opt = pyo.SolverFactory('gurobi')

Both cases provide practically the same value of the objective function and the first case is faster than the second one. However, in some (very few) simulations, a solution cannot be found using the first coding line (i.e., opt = pyo.SolverFactory('gurobi', solver_io='python')), and the following error is returned:

“ValueError: Cannot load a SolverResults object with bad status: error”

Instead, using the second coding line (i.e., opt = pyo.SolverFactory('gurobi')), a solution can always be found, also in the cases when the first coding line fails.

I really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.